# CakePHP save array in wrong format

Tags: cakephp

I have an array in this kind of format:

```
Array
(
   [0] => some text
   [1] => some text
   [2] => some text
   [3] => some text
   [4] => 
   [5] => 
   [6] => some text
   [7] => some text
   [8] => some text
   [9] => 
   [10] => 
   [11] => 
   [12] => 
   [13] => some text
   [14] => some text
)
```

The length of this array can change and sometimes ids are blank as above.

I need to save this array to a MySQL table that has 70 column (all VARCHAR) but it will not save in the above format. I understand that the array needs to be like this:

```
Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
    (
        [fieldname1] => 'value'
        [fieldname2] => 'value'
    )
)
```

How do I modify the above array into the structure below? All the column names are str followed by number that the column is (i.e. str1, str2 etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert you array to something that cake understands, then save it

```
$modelArray = array('ModelName' => array());
foreach( $yourArray as $index => $value ){
    $modelArray['ModelName']['str' . $index] = $value
}
$this->ModelName->save($modelArray);
```